# I want to create a 3D Stacked Carousel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to create a 3D Stacked Carousel in Flutter.

- It should be horizontally scrollable
- It should have an option to make it infinitely scrollable
- It should have onTap/onPressed events
- It should have the ability to show current, previous and next index
- It should be responsive

By the way, I am using Flutter 3.16.0.

The attached picture is what I am expecting:

[image: 3D Stacked Carousal]

I tried using [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider). But it does not look like that picture.

Here's my code:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: widget.allCards.length,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              viewportFraction: 0.25,
              initialPage: 0,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enlargeFactor: 0.25,
              onPageChanged: (int index, CarouselPageChangedReason reason) {},
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
              final DeckCardModel model = widget.allCards[index];
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  autoInsertValue(model);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: Get.width / 2.5,
                  width: Get.width / 4,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: CustomImageWidget(
                      imageUrl: model.image ?? "",
                      rounded: false,
                      typeEnum: TypeEnum.user,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Suggestion: Highlight the requirements that are not achieved yet with your current code

Comment: Hi you can use [This Package](https://github.com/delwar36/overlapped_carousel) for the desired effect.

Comment: I have made some changes that have not been merged into the package you can view them [Here](https://github.com/yashas-hm/overlapped_carousel/tree/skew_card_issue_%232)